# what technologies are available for programmatic video editing?

Tags: video, video-capture

Problem:

Users should be able to upload high resolution video clips from within an app (fat client) that runs on their system. inside this app, i need an framework or lib that is capable of converting an video into an low resolution version.

and on the other side, i need something that is capable of building up video right away from images, animating them in a way that they look like videos.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend the following:

### Windows

- [DirectShow SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Media Foundation SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms696274(VS.85).aspx)
- [Quicktime SDK](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/download/)

### Mac

- [QTKit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/quicktime/qtkit.html)

### Linux

- [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org)

If you need a cross platform solution I would recommend the commercial [MainConcept CodecSDK](http://www.mainconcept.com), which has some of the best video codec implementations around.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say which system, so I start this with an answer for Linux: Have a look at [phonon](http://phonon.kde.org/) and [gstreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/). If you don't mind a command line interface, check out [avidemux](http://avidemux.org/) and mencoder (part of [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/)).

Note that phonon is also available on Windows and Mac.

Comment: phonon does playback, nothing else (yet).