# a cross platform video framework?

Tags: video, quicktime, vlc

we are looking for a cross platform video framework to add to our application, that would allow us to read video files in various formats, get their frames and play them.

One suggestion was VLC/VideoLan, but its a GPL framework and therefore we can't use it 
We thought of Apple's QuickTime, but it can't read WMV files (and needs Apple's approval).
OpenML looks kinda deserted...

any other suggestions?

thanks much

Lior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec) (from the ffmpeg project) is under a LGPL licence, allowing use in a proprietary software.

The public API documentation can be found [here](http://www.inb.uni-luebeck.de/~boehme/using_libavcodec.html) (even if it seems it hasn't been updated for a while, but the project is still active).

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here: [what technologies are available for programmatic video editing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701885/what-technologies-are-available-for-programmatic-video-editing/799541#799541)

As far as I'm concerned the MainConcept CodecSDK gives you good format support across all three platforms, but it isn't free.